# Oracle: Call SP with Out parameter

Tags: oracle, delphi

First of all my knowledge of Oracle is *very* limited.

I have inherited a large Delphi project using Oracle, it have been upgraded to Oracle Cloud. And now I have some problems calling a Stored procedure :

Lets start with the SP's  (It is placed in a package )

```
PROCEDURE GetAccessObjects(AAccessObjects OUT CURSOR_TYPE);
```

Then the Delphi Code:

```
procedure TDBApi.GetAccessObjects(var ResultSet: TADOStoredProc);
var
  SP: TDbStoredProc;
begin
  SP := CreateStoredProc(SQLPackage + 'GetAccessObjects');
  try
    SP.MaxRecords := mrAll;
    SP.Open;
    ResultSet := SP;
  except
    SP.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

When executing the Delphi code I get  the error

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'GETACCESSOBJECTS'

And calling the SP from SQL Developer  (`exec DDK.GetAccessObjects()`) I get the same error.

I can read and understand the error message: Missing parameter. But what beats me is the fact that this code have been running for years. At least 5.

I have at least 10 SP's with this "problem" so its not a simple typo.

So in short how do I move on from here? 
How do I call this SP? 
Can I set some kind of global setting so I don't have to pass this parameter?

Comment: *My* guess would be that in the original Oracle it is permitted to treat a procedure with a single out parameter as if it were a function. At least that is what the code seems to suggest. That seems a fairly arbitrary way to deal with procedures. I guess **SP( ResultSet )** works? If so it looks like you have a compatibility problem between the databases. Unless Oracle Cloud offers some compatibility switch you are probably stuck with changing each individual entry of code.

Comment: I have a meeting with an Oracle consultant tomorrow morning I'll ask him

Comment: You said that OUT parameter's datatype is CURSOR_TYPE. What is it? If it is a custom type, does it exist in your database in the cloud? If not, try to create it and see what happens. Because, I'd say that it is the *wrong type*, not *wrong number* that causes the problem.

Comment: If the stored proc expects an OUT param, then you have to provide an OUT param when you call it. You use the `Params` property of the stored procedure object to set the parameters, and receive the results using GetResults to retrieve the results of the execution. You also typically use `ExecProc` to execute it, not `Open`. I don't know what `TDBStoredProc` is, but the way you're using it isn't typical. What database components are you using?

Comment: See the [TAdoStoredProc documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOStoredProc), which indicates that the `Params` and `ExecProc` I mentioned above are relevant, at least to the `TAdoStoredProc` that is passed in as a parameter to your `GetAccessObjects` procedure.

Comment: @Littlefoot  CURSOR_TYPE is a package

TYPE  CURSOR_TYPE IS REF CURSOR;

Comment: I forgot to dell that GetAccessObjects is defined inside the package CURSOR_TYPE